# Can AES-256 work on Android Devices with API Level 26+?

Tags: java, android, encryption, cryptography, aes

So I'm trying to implement an **AES-256** encryption/decryption to my Android application. However, I don't want to include extra jar to enable **AES-256** as there are export control policies in place.

I found [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/crypto/Cipher.html) in official documentation and it seems like `API level 26+` supports **AES-256** and **AES-128**, is there a way to use this algorithms in older API levels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All versions of AES have been supported on Android for a number of years now.  The policies you refer to are specific to the vanilla JVM, they aren't necessary on Android.  Construct your cipher object like so to use AES-256:

```
byte[] key = ... // Your key material, exactly 32 bytes in length.
byte[] iv = ... // A randomly generated IV, exactly 16 bytes in length.
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, new SecretKey(key, "AES"), new IvParameterSpec(iv));
```

Comment: Thanks, should I specify my algorithm as `"AES-256"` or `"AES"` ?

`SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES-256");`

Comment: @Luke Thanks for your answer. Could explain a little bit more the sentence: `The policies you refer to are specific to the vanilla JVM, they aren't necessary on Android`. Why does Android say in official documentation that AES256 is supported since API 26+?

Answer (score -1):

AES-256 is supported by android. You can use this helper class to make your work easy.

**Warning**: This code is insecure.  It uses a fixed IV and bad key management practices.  Don't use it in production or for anything that requires actual security.

```
import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import java.security.spec.AlgorithmParameterSpec;

public class AES256Cipher {

    public static byte[] encrypt(byte[] ivBytes, byte[] keyBytes, byte[] textBytes)
            throws java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException,
            NoSuchAlgorithmException,
            NoSuchPaddingException,
            InvalidKeyException,
            InvalidAlgorithmParameterException,
            IllegalBlockSizeException,
            BadPaddingException {

        AlgorithmParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes);
        SecretKeySpec newKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
        Cipher cipher = null;
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, newKey, ivSpec);
        return cipher.doFinal(textBytes);
    }

    public static byte[] decrypt(byte[] ivBytes, byte[] keyBytes, byte[] textBytes)
            throws java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException,
            NoSuchAlgorithmException,
            NoSuchPaddingException,
            InvalidKeyException,
            InvalidAlgorithmParameterException,
            IllegalBlockSizeException,
            BadPaddingException {

        AlgorithmParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes);
        SecretKeySpec newKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, newKey, ivSpec);
        return cipher.doFinal(textBytes);
    }
}
```

**USAGE**

```
String key = "e8ffc7e56311679f12b6fc91aa77a5eb";
byte[] keyBytes = key.getBytes("UTF-8");
byte[] ivBytes = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };

String plainText;
byte[] cipherData;
String base64Text;

//############## Request(crypt) ##############
plainText  = "crypt text!!";
cipherData = AES256Cipher.encrypt(ivBytes, keyBytes, plainText.getBytes("UTF-8"));
base64Text = Base64.encodeToString(cipherData, Base64.DEFAULT);
Log.d("encrypt", base64Text);   //BhSJd4mRRJo+fGzpxIOUNg==

//############## Response(decrypt) ##############
base64Text = "72XrlydqnUzVrDfDE7ncnQ==";
cipherData = AES256Cipher.decrypt(ivBytes, keyBytes, Base64.decode(base64Text.getBytes("UTF-8"), Base64.DEFAULT));
plainText = new String(cipherData, "UTF-8");
Log.d("dcrypt", plainText);
```

Comment: Voted down because of the code example. Bad key handling, bad exception handling, zero IV used without warning etc. etc. Don't trust these kind of undocumented, unasked for code blocks when it comes to cryptography - crypto isn't secure when it works..

Comment: @MaartenBodewes i gave him usage sample he will use different Iv. Also fr exception handling he will do according his own need. I haven't much time to write everything.